# Python: cTurtle module not loading

Tags: python, python-3.x

Help I can't get `cTurtle` to load. I get the following error

```
>>> import cTurtle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import cTurtle
TypeError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I have saved the module in the following dir:
`C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages`

Is there something else I am missing, sorry if this is a really newb question but I'd like to play around with the module.  I am using python 3.3.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you download the `cTurtle` module from?

Answer (score 1):

Error seen with python3.3 but not with python3.2.

For some reason line 41 of cTurtle.py contains a NULL-charachter at the end of the line:

```
$ od -t a cTurtle.py.orig | grep -i nul

0003360    -   -   -   -  sp   c   T   u   r   t   l   e   .   p   y nul
```

Remove the NULL-character and the module should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the file in UTF8 and the error message disappeared

Comment: What file did you save as UTF-8?