# Python: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, macos, zelle-graphics

I'm using Max OS X 10.10.3, and I finally got the `graphics.py` to show in Python 3, before it was saying no module existed.

However, now when I try `import graphics`, or `from graphics import *`, I get the message:

```
"source code string cannot contain null bytes"
```

Does any Mac user (using Python 3) perhaps know what is wrong? Has anyone used the Zelle book and his `graphics.py` module? Thanks.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988619/python-cturtle-module-not-loading), that message appears when there's a null byte in the file. It doesn't say how exactly to remove it, but I'd try to edit the file with something like Notepad++.

Comment: From [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/492715), this might remove the null bytes: `python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read().replace("\0", ""))' < graphics.py > graphics_new.py`.

Comment: But how did you create this file? That should answer how you ended up with null bytes in the first place.

Comment: Evert, I didn't create the graphics.py module, it's designed for beginners wanting an introduction to GUI in Python: http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/

Comment: And thanks for the advice, I'll try that out. But how many different lines do I use for those instructions you gave me? Thanks.

Comment: Happened to me also: `od -taz -An -j4031 -N70 -w70 /usr/lib/python3.11/selectors.py` 
`"   "   "   C   h   a   n   g   e  sp   a  sp   r   e   g   i   s   t   e   r   e   d  sp   f   i   l   e  sp   o   b   j   e   c  sp nul nul nul del del del del del del del del del del del del del del del del del del del del  so nul nul dc4 nul nul nul soh   a   t   a   .  nl  >"""Change a registered file objec ...............................ata..<`. How did those characters get into the python library (3.11.8-1)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For posterity: I had the same problem and fixed it using,

```
sed -i 's/\x0//g' FILENAME
```

The file seemed to be messed up in numerous ways (wrong endings, etc); no idea how...

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2399817/230468

Comment: I created my .py file using windows terminal. echo print("test") > test.py and that file was corrupted from start.

Answer (score 34):

I am using Visual Studio Code, the encoding was set to UTF-16 LE.
You can check the encoding on the right bottom side of VSCode. Just click on the encoding and select "save with encoding" and select UTF-8. It worked perfectly.

Comment: I can confirm this. Saving with UTF-8 fixed my problem too. +1

Answer (score 8):

I got this message when I wanted to use `eval` for my input for my function that sometimes it takes string or int/float but when it takes `numpy` numbers, it throws this exception, `eval(number)`.

My solution was `eval(str(number))`.

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered this problem, which is usually caused by the encoding format. You can use Notepad++ to change the encoding format of python files to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error is not from your project source code. This kind of error emerges from your python interpreter. So the best solution is to set your python interpreter in your project **env** directory. or set the interpreters virtual env properly using your IDE's interpreter configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Open your file with an editor that can show you all invisible character.
You will see where is the invalid char, just delete and re-type it.

If you are on mac you can do it with Coda > Open your file > Show invisible characters.

Comment: A hex editor would work for this too.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to python folder `python36/Lib/site-packages/scipy/`
- Open `__init__.py`

Change:

```
from scipy._lib._testutils import PytestTester
```

to:

```
from scipy._lib.test__testutils import PytestTester
```

It worked on my windows 7

Comment: I am using google colab and I got the message: source code string cannot contain null bytes. Do you have any Idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score -2):

I created a file using windows terminal echo "hello" > hello.py and got this issue. I resolved by creating a new file from notepad

Answer (score -2):

My problem was the python interpreter, try changing it to the right python directory path

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30376323)