# Source code contains null value

Tags: python-3.x

Please help me I have coded python for a while and I have basic knowledge, however I have never encountered  this error  even thought I have created this identical code and I didn't have a problem. Have I miss typed please help.

[image: code]

Comment: Where did this error come from? What was your code? What kind of interpreter are you using

Comment: My compiler threw an error. No code found. Please post your code an error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the topics in [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Your question is in danger of being closed if you don't improve it.

Comment: print ("Welcome to the gaming quiz. All of your answers in the quiz must be all lowercase, include spaces and be spelt right")                           
print ("Question 1..")
x = input ("What Call of duty was released in 2015")
if input != x:
    print ("Sorry that was incorrect. Better luck next time")

Comment: thats my code using python 3.6 edited by idle

Comment: You have two `print` functions on one line.

Comment: no sorry thats just  the way it copy pastes you can see the screenshot i linked in the original question

Comment: I'm talking about the screenshot

Comment: sorry but even after i fixed that it still doesnt work

Comment: sounds like you have some non-visible or hidden `NULL` bytes in your code, similar to the behavior in this question [Python: source code string cannot contain null bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes) but of course on Windows. You might want to try copying the text from IDLE into another text editor that can view hidden/non-ascii encoding. Inspect for and remove any unusual characters then paste the "cleaned" text back into IDLE and try running the code again. My guess something near that Grey block between the print and `x`

Comment: Also you could press [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45065685/edit) on your question and `copy`/`paste` the code into your question and let us view the ***text*** to check for hidden characters

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains an **invalid condition**. Use `"Call of Duty: Black Ops III" != x` condition instead of `input != x`