# When importing a module without null bytes I get ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

Python isn't importing modules!

```
marketing
    ├───__init__.py
    ├───analyzation\
    │   ├───__init__.py
    │   ├───analyzer.py
    ├───api\
    ├───test\
    │   ├───test_res\ (not important)
    │   ├───__init__.py
    │   ├───test_analyzer.py
```

Above is my folder structure. So, in `analyzer.py` I have a class `DataSet` and nothing else other than some imports from `pandas` and an import in a method `import random`.

In `test_analyzer.py` I have a class that subclasses `unittest.TestCase`. This script tries to test the following class being imported: `import marketing.analyzation.analyzer` (which doesn't work). The error message is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test_analyzer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import marketing.analyzation.analyzer
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Just to make sure it wasn't some dumb vim error, I retyped `analyzer.py`. Spent at least 2 hours trying to fix this, and another hour surfing stackoverflow and googling, but so far I've come up with nothing. Is it because `test_analyzer.py` is in its own submodule?

Thanks~~~

Comment: Probably dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes but I can't verify now.

Comment: @matt961: If you rename `analyzer.py` to `analyzer2.py` (without changing the import), does the error change?

Comment: @Ryan nope, same error, not even an import error.

Comment: Try `find . -name '*.py' -exec grep -Pa '\x00' {} \;`

Comment: Are you doing this under Windows?  Did you use Notepad?  It smells like the file was saved as Unicode rather than plain ole ASCII.

Comment: @MichaelO. Oh my god. I was creating `__init__.py` by powershell CLI using `'' > __init__.py`. Damn you windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom

Answer (score 0):

Don't use powershell to create files being read by python. Used Vim to create `__init__.py` files instead. Thanks commenters.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with `pytest`.

In my case the problem was in `__init__.py`: the file was created in UTF-16 encoding. I changed encoding to UTF-8 and the problem disappeared.