# Can't run django-admin startproject mysite on windows 10

Tags: django, python-3.x, window

I wanted to learn django but whenever i type in the command "`django-admin startproject mysite`" it keeps giving me an error

Any help please? i am using django 2.2.3 python 3.7.4 on windows 10 home 64bit

```
    C:\Users\kyle kibet>django-admin startproject mystie
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\kyle kibet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\startproject.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.core.management.templates import TemplateCommand
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\templates.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.template import Context, Engine
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .engine import Engine
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .base import Context, Template
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 61, in <module>
    from django.utils.formats import localize
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\formats.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils import dateformat, datetime_safe, numberformat
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateformat.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django.utils.timezone import get_default_timezone, is_aware, is_naive
  File "c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pytz
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: Please include error messages and code samples as *text*, not images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: source code string cannot contain null bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes)

Comment: Somehow the pytz module file has been corrupted. There should be no null bytes inside `.py` files. Try reinstalling the pytz library and make sure you haven't created a pytz module yourself.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\kyle kibet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (2019.1)

Comment: I dint create a pytz module my self. I installed python using install and django using pip!

Comment: run `pip uninstall pytz` then run `pip install pytz`.

Comment: @dfundako its not a duplicate.

Comment: @Moha369 i tried uninstalling pytz but it gives an error

Comment: And how am i supposed to know the error ? :) ... post it.

Comment: @Moha369 [pip uninstall pytz Error](https://i.imgur.com/Jw0IPBL.png)

Comment: Run `pip freeze`, i am confused a little bit.

Comment: @Moha369 Click==7.0
Django==2.2.3
Flask==1.1.1
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
Werkzeug==0.15.5

Comment: Then i suggest you delete the pytz package manually. I mean i can't find another way

Comment: @Moha369 It worked!!! I deleted the pytz package manually and reinstalled it and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @kylekibet Glad it worked ! Good Luck in your project.