# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I have somehow encountered a null byte into my code and i am getting this error:

```
  File "py.py", line 7, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

This is the code which is producing error:

```
from time import sleep
import sys
import requests, json
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import threading
import mysql.connector

print('ok')
```

However, removing the line 'import mysql.connector' the program works just fine?
any suggestions?
I tried removing the error by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes) answer but it did not work?
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reinstall the mysql-connector-python library. It worked just fine :/