# How do I fix "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

I am currently working with python and Sublime to work on a project with to retrieve Tweets. this is the code I am trying to complete, but I am unable to finish importing datafreeze.

```
import datafreeze
import dataset

db = dataset.connect("sqlite:///tweets.db")
result = db["tweets"].all()

datafreeze.freeze(result, format='csv', filename='twittertweets.csv')
print('ding')
```

This is the message I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\Capstone\Archive\Archive\read_database.py", line 2, in <module>
    import datafreeze
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\datafreeze\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datafreeze.app import freeze
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\datafreeze\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import dataset
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\dataset\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dataset.database import Database
  File "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\dataset\database.py", line 11, in <module>
    from alembic.migration import MigrationContext
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Im not sure how to fix the source code string cannot contain null bytes. I have imputed datafreeze through the command prompt, but can't get past this.

Answer (score 0):

The error says: `You have passed null bytes`

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes) is a different library usecase but the error explanation is correct for your case also i guess

You have to remove the null bytes from your database using code (or manually) as the module is not able to.