# pip3 install error: (ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to install the package using pip3, for example, the following command:

```
sudo pip3 install testresources setuptools==49.6.0
```

But, get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

What I have tried:

> Remove pip3 by `purge` and install it again by `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

If it helps, the python version is 3.6.9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes

Comment: @TheBotlyNoob Definitely it is not duplicate! The post that you have mentioned is about a graphic library in MacOS, but mine is about the installation of any package with pip3 in ubuntu!

Comment: Does this still occur if you do a single-user installation? `pip3 install --user testresources setuptools==49.6.0`

Comment: it seems the `pip3` is corrupted.  It is not clear if it's the shortcut `/usr/bin/pip3` or the pip module itself. Can you try running `sudo python3 -m pip install <same packages>`?

Comment: @Marat this command gets the same error!

Comment: If you are using system python, try reinstalling pip. If you have a functional `easy_install`, `easy_install pip3` (sudo if pip is installed systemwide). If you don't have easy_install, and using system pip, `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pip`. If pip was installed in a user folder, remove local pip and [re]install the system one.