# Allowing null bytes in Python3 binary string

Tags: python, null

I am writing a test that is intended to mutate binary data and ensure that my program can read the variations. Null bytes are an important part of this binary protocol.

When I try to save it, however, I encounter the error:

`ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`

The assignment I'm currently trying is:

```
binary_blob = rb"""<value>"""
```

Where `<value>` has the hex representation `0x00`.

How can I modify the assignment to avoid this error? I am using Python 3.9.5.

Comment: You can't put literal null bytes in the source code. Use `\0` in the string literal.

Comment: You can do `binary_blob = bytes([0x00])` if you want to create a `bytes` with a `0x00` byte.

Comment: `'\0'`, `'\u0000'`, and `'\x00'` are all different ways to create a NULL character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: source code string cannot contain null bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes)

Comment: "When I try to save it, however, I encounter the error", what, **exactly** are you doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the null character, which you *can* create with `\0`

```
>>> b"\0"
b'\x00'
>>> ord("\0")
0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I converted my binary data to hex using `xxd` and was able to process it successfully.