# "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes " for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, valueerror

I was trying to learn to create a new window using this code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

But I run into this error,

```
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please post the full error message with traceback. You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0):

The code is absolutely fine and a tkinter window should pop up. A problem has emerged within your editor. Don't know if my answer helps much, but the code is fine and the editor is the problem.

Another thread where this problem is discussed:
[Python: source code string cannot contain null bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233777/16880236)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the link discussion is mostly about Mac and Linux ,And I use Windows

Comment: There was one answer for Windows 7, But I can't find the desired file in my Folder