# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes with django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pycharm

So, i have been getting this error for a week now, and every time I reopen or resume a django project, then i run a python command like `python manage.py runserver` i get this unusually error

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\kate\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "C:\kate\manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.utils.version import get_version
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Meanwhile i saw a solution online that says i should convert it to `UTF-8` which i don't know where to change that or convert that since i use pycharm, VS Code and Sublime for my projects

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes

Comment: @kamaran...i use windows operating system....the error is giving me a lot of problem

Answer (score 0):

so, I figured out what was wrong, it had to do with `django.util.version` so what I did to solve it was to reinstall Django and also change the current version
`pip install django==3.2` since I was currently on Django version 4