# Installed Python 3.9.10 but pip seems to not be working

Tags: python, pip

I have just installed Python 3.9.10, it seemed to be working fine until I tried to install a package with 'pip' I got this error message: "System cannot execute the specified program". I then tried executing this command "python -m pip --version" that resulted in this: [screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBpeW.jpg).

I made sure to add python to the system's PATH and also tried uninstalling and installing again but to no avail. I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: please don't post [images of errors or code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: @2pichar I am sorry I thought it would help to screenshot the command prompt

Comment: pip is inside the Scripts subdirectory of your Python install. So you either need to switch to that directory or add it to your path.

Comment: try `pip3` instead `pip`

Comment: @AyazKhan It says "No module named pip3"

Comment: @bfris I tried adding a PATH to the Scripts folder like you suggested, but it does not seem to work

Comment: install pip https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Null byte means that there are some null characters in pip or pip3 files that's means the file is not downloaded correctly, remove the whole python and then download it. Or try to use this answer:
[1]: [Python: source code string cannot contain null bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes)

It will help you in how to remove these null characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the program, in ehich you got the error.

And then try,

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: If I understood correctly I delete the file "runpy.py" and run the command?

Comment: Okay, I managed to make it work, if anyone has the same problem it is just a corrupted file. I fixed it by asking a friend to copy and send me his working Python directory.

Comment: Beaware of using modules which are not listed on official python site. Glad to help you. Thank you.