# Django runserver - ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, django, python-3.10

I'm trying to run my Django application, which used to work fine before. Now, it is showing this strange error, which seems like coming from Django.

Django Version: 4.1

Python Version: 3.10.6 (Docker Image python:3.10.6)

```py
 django shell commands
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/srv/project/./manage.py", line 9, in <module>
     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
     from django.apps import apps
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 13, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 62, in AppConfig
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 27, in __init__
     from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango50Warning
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 5, in <module>
     from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
 ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: This error means that, the problem is not in code, problem is in interpreter

Comment: @CurlyError how do you modify files in your project. Are you using notepad/IDE? On windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: source code string cannot contain null bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes)

Comment: No, already checked that. After running `docker system prune -a` to clean everything and rebuilding it, it started working.