# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes importing pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

When i try to import pandas in a python code it gives me the error:

```
    File "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\alkemy\src\py_functions\transform_univ_jfk.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import (
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel import (
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel._base import (
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 75, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers import TextParser
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers.readers import (
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I was using python until about a month ago without errors, my cousin used my computer for a few days and I don't know what she did, I reinstalled python and it still gives me errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: source code string cannot contain null bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes)

Comment: i think it doesnt. I use windows 10.