# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes in py-cord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

My code looks like this.

```py
import discord

# ...
```

When I try to run the program, I get the following error: *ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes* in line **import discord**

I have Python version 3.9.0 x64.
I use the latest version of the py-cord library for Discord.
I tried running it on an older version, but it didn't help. Everything was fine before the Windows 10 update. What i need to do ?

Comment: If it's a windows 10 update thing, I don't believe we have enough details

Comment: It may be a UTF issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.
I reinstalled py-cord again after restarting the computer, and everything worked!